# format NSString to hold ascii value rather than unicode characters

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, unicode, nsstring

I have a string absoluteUrl of any file and some plist file entries for the directory files (where one entry is for the absoluteUrl).

`NSString *absoluteURL = @"/Users/macbookpro/abc - 20404_1_C-not-001-Akustiske forhold i glassgården.pdf";`

`NSDictionary *plistData` has some dictionary value:

**"/Users/macbookpro/abc - 20404_1_C-not-001-Akustiske forhold i glassg\U00e5rden - Drammensveien 134.pdf" = { };**

"/Users/macbookpro/abc - 24563_1_A-auronfred.pdf" = { };

...

here when i try to get one dictionary from plistData:

`NSMutableDictionary *filePlistData = [plistData valueForKey:absoluteURL];`

Now when i try to look up plist file the **"å"** is in UTF16 format but when i tried to print plistData "å" is converted to **"\U00e5"** which is the main reason why i get filePlistData = "nil".

Now what should i try to get rid from this??

thank you all of you for ur tremendous support.

Comment: Internally, `NSString` uses UTF-16 and so the comparison should have worked, shouldn't it?  Also there is no ASCII equivalent of the 'å' character as you know the Americans don't use that character in their language.

Comment: Show me your coding that actually what you have tried till now.

Comment: What code are you using to compare the strings?

Comment: NSString *absoluteURL = [url path];
 NSMutableDictionary *filePlistData = [plistData valueForKey:absoluteURL]; where: absoluteUrl = "/Users/macbookpro/abc - 20404_1_C-not-001-Akustiske forhold i glassgården - Drammensveien 134.pdf"
and plistData = "/Users/macbookpro/abc - 20404_1_C-not-001-Akustiske forhold i glassg\U00e5rden - Drammensveien 134.pdf" =     {
        
    };
 "/Users/macbookpro/abc - 20405_1_Test File.docx" =     {
        
    };

Comment: Here i get nil value in filePlistData

Comment: Please edit your question with that code, it's easier to read than in comment and in fact be helpful for others that could have the same issue to not look into each comments.

Comment: hello @Larme and everyone I have edited the question with complete details of the scenario.

Comment: @SmitBaranwal plz edit the question with the code you put in a comment and format everything

Comment: @Daij-Djan I have formatted the question please have a look if u can provide a solution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked a lot and got a solution to use :

```
precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping
```

to read plist data